# Which manga is this smiling man from?

Tags: tao-tie-jie

[image: in Which ( manga - manhwa -or manhua ) is this?]

I can't seem to find this anywhere I've looked.

All I remember is that:

- This man is a deity or demon of some sort.
- He threatened the villagers not to come near his mountain, but it
  turned out that he found a baby and wanted to raise it there.
- The
  baby grew in to a man, and soon he fell in love with a lady who loved
  him back. However, the villagers didn't like that, and because of a
  jealous villager, they killed them both. Years have passed and the
  deity/demon found them reincarnated and married with a son.

Does anyone know which manga is this from?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for [**Tao Tie Jie**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/19246/Tao_Tie_Jie) . The image you posted is from volume 1 chapter 2.

[image: pic]